# Quicklook/QLPreviewController delegate methods are not calling in iOS 10 Xcode 8

Tags: objective-c, ios10, xcode8, quicklook, qlpreviewcontroller

Currently I am testing my current version in iOS10. I am using **Xcode 8** beta 6 for testing. Here **Quicklook/QLPreviewController delegate methods are not calling.** This code set had been worked with XCode 7 and iOS 9.3 versions. I checked this issue in Apple Developer forum. But could not find a answer. Anyone have fixed this issue? (I am using Objective-C)

How to use Quicklook/QLPreviewController in XCode 8 (**iOS 10**)?

//----------------- SOLUTION for iOS 10 ( previewer as a subview)  -------------------

This issue is occurred when you add the the previewer as a subview. Then we are using below code lines mainly in iOS 9.3 and below versions.

```
[self addChildViewController:previewer];
self.view addSubview:previewer.view];
[previewer didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

In iOS 10 issue comes due to the below code line.

```
[self addChildViewController:previewer];
```

For iOS 10 we need to check the version and add above code line. Below is the working code set.

```
    QLPreviewController* previewer = [[QLPreviewController alloc] init];

    previewer.dataSource = self;
    previewer.delegate = self;
    // To avoid iOS 10 previewer issue.
    if (SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"10.0")) {
        [self addChildViewController:previewer];
    }
    CGFloat width = self.view.frame.size.width;
    CGFloat height = self.view.frame.size.height;
    previewer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 102, width, height-300);
    [self.view addSubview:previewer.view];

    [previewer didMoveToParentViewController:self];
```

Comment: Thanks, works with Xamarin.iOS too.

Answer (score 1):

I met this problem too, but I can't fix this issue by your solution..
Here is my code:

```
QLPreviewController *preview = [[QLPreviewController alloc] init];
[preview setDataSource:self];
[preview setDelegate:self];

if(SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"10.0"))
{
    [self addChildViewController:preview];
}

[preview didMoveToParentViewController:self];
[self.view addSubview:preview.view];
```

Comment: @ridvankucuk Still do you have issue?