# Unable to add QLPreviewController as childViewController iOS10

Tags: ios, swift, ios10, qlpreviewcontroller

I am trying to add QLPreviewController as childViewController. However I got no success on iOS10. I have checked this [link.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39239330/quicklook-qlpreviewcontroller-delegate-methods-are-not-calling-in-ios-10-xcode-8). No success. Here is my code:

```
let previewController:QLPreviewController = QLPreviewController()

previewController.dataSource = self
previewController.currentPreviewItemIndex = 0

self.addChildViewController(previewController)
self.view.addSubview(previewController.view)
previewController.view.didMoveToSuperview()
```

This code block works on the iOS9. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In this case, the view you are has a zero rect. That is why it is not visible. You can solve it in two different ways:
- Using auto layout.
- Setting to frame and the autoresizing mask:

```
previewController.view.frame = self.view.frame;
self.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
```